# how to match 477xx with regular expression

Tags: python, regex

The input string must be in the format `"477xx"`, where the `x` may be `0`-`9` or whitespace, and the length muse be 5. I want to find the following targets with a regular expression.

```
["477  ", "4770 ", "4771 ", "4781 "]
```

How can I do it? This is my rough idea: `"477[0,1,8,9]?"`

Comment: So for instance `477 1` (with a ` ` inside) should be matched?

Answer (score 6):

You can use the following regex:

```
 ^477[0-9\s]{2}$
```

Mind that "4781 " is not matched as it does not start with "477".

Here is the [demo](https://regex101.com/r/xU2aI8/1).

And an example code on [Tutorialspoint](http://goo.gl/AlmjPd):

```
p = re.compile(ur'^477[0-9\s]{2}$', re.MULTILINE)
test_str = u"477  \n4770 \n4771 \n4781 "
arr = re.findall(p, test_str)
print  arr
```